# See if object from one dataframe appears in other dataframe, when one has numbers added (e.g. string, string1)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with actor names (their types are object) that look like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({Actors: [Christian Bale, Ben Kingsley, Halley Bailey, Aaron Paul, etc...]
df2 = pd.read_csv({id: [Halley Bailey - 1998, Coco Jones – 1998, etc...]
```

Normally I would use the following code to find if one item is present in another dataframe but due to the numbers in the second dataframe I get 0 matches. Is there any smart way of going over this?

```
df.assign(indf=df.Actors.isin(df_actor_list.id).astype(int))
```

The code above did not work obviously

Answer (score 1):

You can [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the actor names from `df2['id']` and check if `df['Actors']` is in it:

```
df.assign(indf=df['Actors'].isin(df2['id'].str.extract('(.*)(?=\s[-–])',
                                 expand=False)).astype(int))
```

output:

```
           Actors  indf
0  Christian Bale     0
1    Ben Kingsley     0
2   Halley Bailey     1
3      Aaron Paul     0
```

Another, more generic, approach relying on a regex:

```
import re
regex = '|'.join(map(re.escape, df['Actors']))
# 'Christian\\ Bale|Ben\\ Kingsley|Halley\\ Bailey|Aaron\\ Paul'

actors = df2['id'].str.extract(f'({regex})', expand=False).dropna()

df.assign(indf=df['Actors'].isin(actors).astype(int))
```

used inputs:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Actors': ['Christian Bale', 'Ben Kingsley', 'Halley Bailey', 'Aaron Paul']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['Halley Bailey - 1998', 'Coco Jones – 1998']})
```

Comment: Thanks! The regex solution works, the first one gave me a `TypeError: string indices must be integers`, I'm not sure why, but I'll look it up.